# How to handle multiple layout in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

we have lots of panel in out Application like admin , teacher principal , student , parent etc .

Each panel have its own layout 
So upon login we handle this using WelcomeController

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        return render :home if current_user.nil?
        return render :admin if current_user.super?
        return redirect_to("/student/lesson") if current_user.student?
        return redirect_to("/teacher/lesson") if current_user.teacher?
        return render "layouts/principal" if current_user.principal?
        return render "layouts/coordinator" if current_user.coordinator?
        return render "layouts/viceprincipal" if current_user.viceprincipal?
        return render "layouts/parent" if current_user.parent?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So right now for getting data from controller we redirect to his route Like for Student

```
return redirect_to("/student/lesson") if current_user.student?
```

but we wants that on URL **/** we get data from controller . 
So my problem is how to get data ?   So we can use in views

I am new to Rails , if I am using something wrong Please let me know . Will I get data from Model ?

In routes we use

```
get '/student/lesson', to: 'student_lesson_plan#index', as: 'student_lesson'
```

And from index Action we have variables which we use . So I want 
instead of

`return redirect_to("/student/lesson") if current_user.student?`
something like this

```
return render "layouts/student" if current_user.student?
```

And I can use those variables which I initialize in `student_lesson_plan#index` or from another place

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Do you need help to get different application layouts working or you just want to understand how to pass var from controller to views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application I would set something like this to get different layout depending on conditions:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  layout :layout_by_user_types # works like a before action 

  def layout_by_user_types
    if current_user.student?
      "students/application"
    elsif current_user.other_condition?
      "other_name_space/application" 
    else
      "application"
    end
  end

end
```

In my views folder I would separate the different layouts so I can call different css/js if needed ...

```
-views
  -layouts
    -students
      -_my_partials.html.erb
      -application.html.erb
    -other_users
      -_my_partials.html.erb
      -application.html.erb
....
```

The basic understanding of how we get info from models to views thanks to the controllers:

In a controller

```
class StudentController < ApplicationController

  def_index
   @my_var_i_want_in_my_view = Student.my_query_to_database
   @my_var_i_want_in_my_view_too = Student.my_super_action_that_will_give_some_data_and_that_is_a_method_in_my_model
  end

end
```

Then in the view you can grab and use `@my_var_i_want_in_my_view`

Comment: hmm , now I am do like this if current_user.parent?
          @name=StudentLessonPlan.studentReportForParent
          return render "layouts/parent"
        end

Comment: I'll update my answer so you can get how var are passed from model to controller to views

Comment: In your case I would namespace a little or at least redirect to controllers that are made for each ressources to get my code cleaner. (students_controller, teachers_controller, and so on)

Comment: I am new to Rails have experience in Node.js , get this project from freelance.now stuck in Rails Concept

Comment: Could you plz elaborate . I didn't get

Comment: I would definitely advise you to read a little to get this clear like the rails guide, maybe some screencasts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108705/discussion-between-abhaygarg12493-and-coding-addicted).